# TikZ coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In a diagram made with Ti*k*Z, I saw this coordinate relative to the node “c”: `(c.130)`, 130 being an angle in degrees.

Can someone tell me why the distance between the two points obtained is not specified?

What is this distance? What Ti*k*Z instruction is this taken from?

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(c){$\bullet$};
\draw(c.130) node[red]{$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please put your code between ``` ``` to have it formatted as a block. My guess is `c.130` refers to  the anchor that is at 130° instead of naming it north west west. https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.5.1.

Comment: In addition to the answers, I will add that it is very bad code for drawing circles. The sizes and distance(and even the shape) depend on the font used. In the pictures below, it can be seen that the circle is not even centered on the coordinate.

Comment: `c.130` is a *border anchor*; you can learn more looking at the description of `angle` coordinate here: https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#tikz/anchor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the guess made by @anis is right:

- `\node[draw=gray!20](c){$\bullet$};` puts a tight rectangle (default shape) around this node
- `\draw(c.130) node[red]{$\bullet$};` is a polar reference from (c) at 130deg ON the default shape; replacing the `.` with `:` results in a compile error
- for reference, `\draw(c.west) node[orange]{$\bullet$};` puts an orange dot on the nodes shape
- for reference, `\draw[blue!50] (0,0) -- (25:2);` draws a blue line at 25deg 2cm apart

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=gray!20](c){$\bullet$};
    \draw(c.130) node[red]{$\bullet$};
    \draw(c.west) node[orange]{$\bullet$};
    
    \draw[blue!50] (0,0) -- (25:2);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For reference, here's the same code but with `inner sep=7mm` for the node, making the default shape larger:

[image: inner sep=7mm]

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=gray!20,inner sep=7mm](c){$\bullet$};
    \draw(c.130) node[red]{$\bullet$};
    \draw(c.west) node[orange]{$\bullet$};
    
    \draw[blue!50] (0,0) -- (25:2);
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: For some reason the image doesn't show up?

Comment: I can see them.

Comment: Thanks. I still can‘t. IT miracles … ;-)

Comment: A big thank you to all of you, I finally understood.

Comment: So you can accept one of the answers to let everyone know that it's solved for you. And maybe vote (if you can already). In addition, as @hpekristiansen said, you may want to find another method if you need to draw circles. Feel free to ask another question when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your first point (`bullet`) is inside a `node` for which you didn't define any size or shape, so it's adjusted to its content (the bullet) and has the default rectangular shape. Then, by `\draw(c.130) node[red]{$\bullet$};` you place another node on the edge of this first node, but at 130°.

See the code below (with a larger `inner sep` to help you visualize it).
I added the parameter `draw` to the nodes on the edges, just to make you understand the way it's placed and drawn. If you just want to draw a filled circle, you'll have to do this differently.

On a rectangluar shaped first node:
[image: on a rectangluar shaped node]

On a circular shaped node:
[image: on a circular shaped node]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw=cyan,inner sep=10mm](c){$\bullet$};
        \foreach \angle [evaluate = \angle as \shad using \angle+10] in {0,30,60,90}
        \draw(c.\angle) node[draw,blue!\shad]{$\bullet$};
        \draw(c.130) node[red]{$\bullet$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[circle,draw=cyan,inner sep=10mm](c){$\bullet$};
        \foreach \angle [evaluate = \angle as \shad using \angle+10] in {0,30,60,90}
        \draw(c.\angle) node[draw,blue!\shad]{$\bullet$};
        \draw(c.130) node[red]{$\bullet$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```